# Creating nodes with blank values from a csv file in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two columns in CSV file - `Report` and `Actuals Data` (with some blank/null values under Actuals Data).
Following is the code which I used to create relationship between `Report` and `Actuals Data`:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:RegReport) ASSERT c.name is UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file:///Dummy.csv' AS test
MERGE (n:RegReport {name: test.RegReport})

WITH test, n
FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN test.`Actuals Data` IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
MERGE (p:ActualsData{value: test.`Actuals Data`})
MERGE (n)-[:value]->(p)
)
```

The return that I got was:

> (no changes, no rows)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So your CSV has two columns, named `RegReport` & `Actuals Data` ?
Are you sure that `Actuals Data` is `null` ? Is it not empty instead ? To test bith you can use `WHEN coalesce(test.`Actuals Data`, "")=""`

Comment: Please, share with us a sample data of your CSV file.

Comment: @ Bruno Peres Here is a sample of the data
Report, Actuals Data                                                                                    
FR Y-14A, AA
FR Y-14A,
FR Y-9C, AB

Comment: @logisima When I say Actuals Data is null I mean, it has some cells which are blank and some which have value

Comment: Yes but empty can be the string '' or just empty so `null`. Can you give us the result of this `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file:///Dummy.csv' AS test RETURN test LIMIT 2` ?

Comment: @logisima - here is the output:
test                          │
╞══════════════════════════════╡
│{Report: FR Y-14A, ActualsData│
│: (null)}                     │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{Report: FR Y-14A, ActualsData│
│: AA}

Answer (score 1):

According to the result of `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file:///Dummy.csv' AS test RETURN test LIMIT 2` your cypher script should be this one :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file:///Dummy.csv' AS test
MERGE (n:RegReport {name: test.`Report`})

WITH test, n
FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN test.`ActualsData` IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END |
MERGE (p:ActualsData{value: test.`ActualsData`})
MERGE (n)-[:value]->(p)
)
```

Hearders of your CSV file are `Report` and `ActualsData`, and not `RegReport` & `Actuals Data`.

Comment: @logisma : But isnt this supposed to be the label name which according to my understanding is something that we have the flexibility to choose. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not talking about the label of your nodes but about your CSV columns. For the labels yes you can put whatever you want.  But if you look at the output you give to me, Neo4j doesn't see any RegReport column for example.

Comment: @logisma : I totally agree with what you are saying.. but when I put in n: RegReport - this is where it decides to give the label name and when I am doing test.Report - this is where it should read from the csv files. Isn't it ?